# event.stopPropagation Firefox

Tags: javascript, stoppropagation

I have a JavaScript function that needs to stop bubbling.  The code as I have it looks like this.

```
function clickedOrderSample(element, product, color, entry_id) {
    var cname ; 
    cname = element.className ;
    event.stopPropagation ? event.stopPropagation() : (event.cancelBubble=true) ;
    if (cname == 'orderSample' ) {
        window.location="index.php?/shop/add_to_cart/" + entry_id + "/" + color ;
    } else {
        window.location="index.php?/shop/products/" + product + "/" + color ;
    }
}
```

This is not working in FireFox 39.0.  The problem is with the line.

```
event.stopPropagation ? event.stopPropagation() : (event.cancelBubble=true) ;
```

Is there a different way to write this so it will work with all browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your handler doesn't define an `event` parameter, which is available as a global in Chrome and IE but not Firefox.

Change your handler to add `event` to the beginning of the formal parameters list.

I assume the rest of the parameters are bound with `.bind()` or are passed via closure. If `.bind()` was used, then you'd actually need to add it as the *last* parameter.

If you're using a closure, then probably the actual bound handler needs to define the `event` parameter and pass it along.

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't see the question being asked before and am new to javascript so thanks for your patience.